# How would Europeans fend themselfs in a Zombie apocalypse?

Tags: apocalypse, survival, zombies

Most of zombie apocalypse movies, series, comics, etc. are set in the United States, but how an outbreak look like in European countries? Would it be different at all?

Comment: There *are* still guns. Sometimes exaggeratedly the USA is thought of as a land where everyone is armed at all times. That's not really true, even if there is more access to firearms. In "Europe" (there really isn't *one* thing but still) the laws might be stricter but it's a huge exaggeration to suggests there are no guns. The military would have them, at the very least, and if they are gone as you suggest, then people could just go raid their storage. And there are hunters or hobby shooters who also have personal firearms. Moreover Europe is a diverse place - access to guns still varies.

Comment: France has lots of guns around. You just have to join one of the organizations that manages them and keeps people from just free carrying them into nightclubs. In the USA, we might call them "militias". *ahem*

Comment: *Some* European countries (e.g., the United Kingdom) have very strict gun laws. Other European countries (e.g., France) have much less strict gun laws. Yet other European countries (e.g., Norway or Finland) are pretty much as liberal as some U.S. states with respect to guns. ("Liberal" in the European sense, that is, generous.) Europe is a very diverse place, even if speaking only of the E.U. and the E.E.A. (And that's not to mention some countries east of the E.U. where gun laws are purely theoretical.)

Comment: Even in the UK the laws aren't as strict as you might think, when it comes to rifles and shotguns, for those that can be bothered to jump through all the bureaucratic hoops. Its just that there's no culture of gun ownership. Not that it matters: a bit of careful research shows that most documented zombie apocalypses happened in the US, and all those guns accomplished very little. So there you go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Guns are the worst Zombie weapon anyway

First, guns are noisy which attracts more of the shambling dead to you location. Second, guns require specialized ammunition that needs gunpowder and machined (or molded) metal (I guess you could fill a shot-shell with random gunk). Lastly, guns have a bunch of moving parts that you will need to maintain to ensure it's still useful. On top of all that, if you have a gun finding bullets doesn't mean your gun can shoot them.

## Cars

While not fuel efficient an armoured car with some spikes or some such weapon on the front could just ram through the zombies. Cars and metal plating wouldn't be particularly hard to find. This method still requires a bunch of maintenance and doesn't protect you while you're repairing or moving plating to a new vehicle

## Melee

While not the best of options, you can always make a reach weapon like a glaive and some thick leather for protection. This method is probably the most dangerous, as you still have to get within several meters of your targets and it would be hard to take out many zombies at once. These types of weapons do have the advantage of being fairly easy to make, you just need a big enough blade and a long enough stick.

## Bows

A crossbow might be the easiest way, although you run into the moving parts that can break thing again. A regular bow and arrow would be quiet, have a decent range, and you can make your own ammo for it with some trial, error, and/or training. Obviously a bow has other requirements, like having a high enough draw strength to get a better range and stopping power, and aiming requires more practice than a gun or crossbow does.

## Javelins

If you lack the ability to create a bow, you can always just huck some medium sized sharpened sticks in the direction of the dead.

Comment: Shooting a bow accurately into the head of something moving is not straightfoward. Making your own arrows is also a non-trivial skill to try and acquire in a peri-apocalyptic sitaution. Throwing spears may _seem_ simpler, but they're not. Really, guns are better than most of your suggestions...

Comment: @StarfishPrime What happens when you run out of bullets? Where do you find the gun powder to make more? Sure, making a bow and arrow is non-trivial, but if the world has ended you've got tons of time to perfect it

Comment: Not when everyone's been eaten, which is the penalty for not learning fast enough, which is exactly what will befall most people. Guns though... refilling spent cartridges is possible. Casting new bullets is easy. Manufacturing smokeless propellant isn't entirely trivial, but black powder is much more straightfoward.

Comment: Guns are a bad choice because the sound brings more zombies. Crossbow is generally the best weapon as it's quiet and the bolts can usually be retrieved. It's also easier to use than a bow

Comment: As I understand it most European homes have some medieval melee weapons hanging on the walls, in use as doorstops, etc.  These would no doubt be buffed up and put to use.

Comment: @Willk maybe I've not been in enough European homes but I don't think I've seen medieval weapons on walls. Unless you count the kitchen - hanging cooking utensils there is common and some kitchens even have a [knife magnet](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71FrU4jqURL._AC_SX466_.jpg). I've one and it's pretty useful. I don't consider it a "weapon rack" or anything similar, though.

Comment: @VLAZ - Did your hosts have advance notice you were visiting?  Maybe they put them out of sight, along with the good scotch.